# Path conflict between server and client

Tags: javascript, python, django, electron

I have a client React app (Electron) that is running on `http://localhost:3000/`

My Django server has this path in the whitelist:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "http://localhost:3000"
]
```

The problem is that Python doesn't let me add the `/` at the end of the path.
If I'm calling the server like it is right now it won't work.

[image]

So can I force Django to accept my url with the `/` at the end? or maybe change it from my React client.

Comment: Could you share your url conf?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can try

**1. Auto-add trailing slash**

Make sure `'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware'` is within your middle_wares in `settings.py`

In addition, make sure `APPEND_SLASH = True` is added to your settings.

**2. Define routes with slash**

in your URL conf, make sure you add the trailing slash to the end of your route. This way, you wouldn't see the error.

**3. Make trailing slash optional**

You can make adding the trailing slash optional by defining such a route:

```
from django.urls import re_path
re_path(about/?$', views.appmain, name="main")
```

Note: question mark matches zero or one `/` in the URL. It accepts both `localhost:8000/about` and `localhost:8000/about/`

Comment: I read more into it and I don't even know if they should be the same. I changed a bit and now the referer is `http://localhost:3000/login` meanwhile the origin is `http://localhost:3000`. I think the origin as it is now should be enough. The referer is changing anyway.